# Setting up a simple ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working with [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 4 and am attempting to write a really basic route, but it's not working and getting very frustrated with it!

I want the URL http://www.mywebsite.com/my-page to trigger the controller called *Page* and the action method *Index*.

I have no other route setup apart from this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "my-page",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" }
);
```

Is there something incorrect with my setup or where am I going wrong?

The error I get is:

> The controller for path '/my-page' was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: This works fine from a default Mvc website. Can you show us the entire RouteConfig?

Comment: your route seems good. add your controller class to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is you are trying to override the default route.  In MVC4, the routes are defined in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs.  The "Default" route should be the LAST route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then, for your specific route, use the following BEFORE the default route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyPage",
            url: "my-page",
            defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Fianlly, ensure you have a controller PageController.cs with an action Index and a View Views/Page/Index.cshtml:

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```